# Extract substring from text

Tags: java, substring

I'm writing a parser, where it reads all lines in a particular file and processes it!! I got stuck with this substring `Abc [123]` where `ABC` should be stored at as one string, and `123` as other string.so i came up with this solution

```
lines.get(i).substring(0,lines.get(i).lastIndexOf("["))
```

this get me the string `abc`

```
lines.get(i).substring(lines.get(i).lastIndexOf("["));
```

and aboveone gets me the string `123]` but i dont want `]` at last any updation can i make for my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
lines.get(i).substring(lines.get(i).lastIndexOf("["));
```

to

```
lines.get(i).substring(lines.get(i).lastIndexOf("[") + 1,lines.get(i).lastIndexOf("]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a regular expression in combination with groups?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z ]{1,})([\[]{1})([0-9]{1,})");
for(String line : lines){
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
  while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("group 3: " + matcher.group(3));
  }
}
```